# Брать за фук — этимология

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова "фук"?

Comment: Задания, тем более домашние, не выполняются... Почти дословно из Правил на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

**ФУК**

> 1. только ед. Действие по гл. фукнуть во 2 знач. - фукать.
> 2. Шашка, которую фукнул партнер (см. фукнуть во 2 знач.). Взять фук.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

---

[ФУ́КНУТЬ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1079290)

> 2. что. Снять у противника с доски шашку при его ошибке в игре. Он у меня две шашки фукнул.
>
>    ---

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)

**ФУКНУТЬ** ...6. В шашечной игре: взять фуку <Фукать

**ФУК**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Этимология:](https://ru-etymology.livejournal.com/1204861.html)

Звукоподражание.

Фасмер:  [От звукоподражательного *fu](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-14700.htm)

> Когда «берешь за фук», надо было перевернуть шашку обратной стороной и
>   дунуть в нее, получался такой специфический звук.
>
> ---
>
> Вспомните, что слово это произносят во время игры в шашки, сопровождая
>   его таким движением: берут шашку, которой игрок прозевал (профукал)
>   пойти, и дуют коротко на нее. Так что, скорее всего, происходит слово
>   от глагола "фукать" - дуть.

---

Хозяйке на заметку:

1. [Почему и как исчез фук в шашках](https://luckforfree.com/checkers/why-did-fuk-in-checkers-disappear/);
2. [Выражение «взять за фук».](https://ckachat-check.ru/shashki-pravila/nichya-v-shashkax.html)

Answer (score 0):

В шашках "взять за фук" означало то, что играющий не сделал обязательного хода, не побил шашку противника. Вместо него он сделал другой ход.
При очередном ходе противник берёт эту шашку "за фук".
Это означает, что играющий "профукал" шашку или, говоря по русски прое..л. Вспомните, что означает слово Fuck в английском языке, вы его часто слышите в американских фильмах про уголовников. Вот скриншот из Яндекс переводчика.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сейчас открыл английский словарь и прикололся: "What have you been doing today? Oh, nothing, just fucking off." Что ты сегодня делал? Ох, ничего, просто слонялся.